# looping a command to varying number of files in subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to find a way to write a script that executes a command on varying number of files in subdirectories. I have 72 subdirectories each with varying number of sample files (fastq.gz files) with the one containing the most having 20 sample files. I used the following command but it gives me alot of empty folders and files when the number of files is less than 20 in a subdirectory.

```
#!/bin/sh
TOPHAT_BINARY=/home/alex/tools/tophat-2.1.0.Linux_x86_64/tophat2
GENE_REFERENCE=/home/alex/toxo/ref/genes/ToxoDB-27_TgondiiME49.gff
BOWTIE_INDEX=/home/alex/toxo/ref/bwt/ToxoDB-27_TgondiiME49_Genome
P=10 #use 10 threads
for FILE_ID in {001..072}
do
 for SAMPLE_ID in {001..020}
 do
 $TOPHAT_BINARY -G $GENE_REFERENCE -p $P -o /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/sample_${SAMPLE_ID} $BOWTIE_INDEX /home/junya/bioinfo/NGS/original/Nishikawa.cell/rename_and_link/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/*_${SAMPLE_ID}.fastq.gz &
 mv /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/sample_${SAMPLE_ID}/accepted_hits.bam /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/sample_${SAMPLE_ID}.bam
 done
done
```

how do i edit the script

```
for SAMPLE_ID in {001..020}
```

so that the command only applies to the specific number of files in a particular subdirectory without outputting empty files?

Some of the subdirectories contain 2, 3, 10, 16 etc number of files so I just did 20 so if a subdirectory has 2 sample files then the output will contain 18 empty files....I added a command to remove all empty files at the end and it worked but Is there any other way to specify only the files contained in multiple subdirectories?

```
## secure and fast version ###
find /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID} -type f -empty -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} /bin/rm "{}"
```

Comment: You could test for the existence of the file beforehand perhaps?

Comment: Some of the subdirectories contain 2, 3, 10, 16 etc number of files so I just did 20 so if a subdirectory has 2 sample files then the output will contain 18 empty files....I added a command to remove all empty files at the end and it worked but Is there any other way to specify only the files contained in multiple subdirectories?

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Mel's answer has solved your problem; here's another variation. Instead of looping over a large range of SAMPLE_ID's (and what if you eventually end up with more than your expected 20?), I changed the loop so that it uses bash's filename expansion to loop over all and only the sample_* files that actually exist in /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID}. In order to get your original value of SAMPLE_ID back, I use [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to retrieve the last three charcters from the SAMPLE_ID filename. Note that this breaks if you end up with more than 999 sample_* files!

I also changed your she-bang header line to explicitly call bash (via env) because if called as /bin/sh, bash will try to emulate Bourne shell, and lose features of the Bourne Again SHell (like fancy Parameter Expansion!).

As a side bonus, using SAMPLE_FILE in this way makes the commands a little bit shorter & easier to read!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TOPHAT_BINARY=/home/alex/tools/tophat-2.1.0.Linux_x86_64/tophat2
GENE_REFERENCE=/home/alex/toxo/ref/genes/ToxoDB-27_TgondiiME49.gff
BOWTIE_INDEX=/home/alex/toxo/ref/bwt/ToxoDB-27_TgondiiME49_Genome
P=10 #use 10 threads
for FILE_ID in {001..003}
do
  for SAMPLE_FILE in /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/sample_*
  do
    SAMPLE_ID=${SAMPLE_FILE: -3}
    $TOPHAT_BINARY -G $GENE_REFERENCE -p $P -o $SAMPLE_FILE $BOWTIE_INDEX /home/junya/bioinfo/NGS/original/Nishikawa.cell/rename_and_link/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/*_${SAMPLE_ID}.fastq.gz
    mv ${SAMPLE_FILE}/accepted_hits.bam ${SAMPLE_FILE}/sample_${SAMPLE_ID}.bam
    echo
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

right after second `do` line, insert a new line and type

```
if [ -a /home/alex/toxo/alignments/Nishi_${FILE_ID}/sample_${SAMPLE_ID} ] ; then
```

and right before the first `done` line, again, insert a new line and type

```
fi
```

this will check the existence of the file before trying to process it. If it doesn't exist, it will skip over that SAMPLE_ID value.

Comment: That path is the output directory the input directory is /home/junya/bioinfo/NGS/original/Nishikawa.cell/rename_and_link/Nishi_${FILE_ID}. the problem is i have to create the output directories first so they are all empty. furthermore some will definitely remain empty after the run

Comment: Why not use `-e` instead of `-a`?  `-e` is specified in POSIX; `-a` is not.